# How to have 2 way interaction in audio through red5 server

Tags: flash, flex4, streaming, audio-streaming, red5

I am a newbie in Flash development.I am trying to create a flash(i have done that and can save the stream to red 5 server) in which i have the option to publish my own microphone stream to red5 server and also, i have the option to listen to a already published stream.This same flash i will be using on two different machines.I will publish the microphone from both the machines by giving the streams different names.Then i will try to open the streams from opposite machines so that i can have the 2 way audio chatting from the 2 machines.

e.g from machine 1 the stream published was Stream1.
    from machine 2 the stream published was Stream2.

```
The stream played from machine 1 was Stream2.
The stream played from machine 2 was Stream1.
```

The problem which i am facing is that i have the difficulty to attain the 2 way communication .That is i am not able to hear the stream 2 from 1st machine.When i publish the stream from second machine then my first stream gets disconnected and is overridden by second stream.
Can anyone give me a proper suggestion for it,to how to rectify this to attain a gud 2 way connection or how can i stream 2 audios together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to have an audio chatting application using red5 and flex 4.5 you can try the code bellow. It should be tuned to your purpose of course:

Audio Chat machine 1

```
    <mx:Script>
     <![CDATA[
         import mx.controls.Alert;
         
         private var netConnection:NetConnection;
         private var InsertStream:NetStream;
         private var getStream:NetStream;
         private var connectionUrl:String="rtmp://YOURSERVER/vchat";
         
         private function init():void
         {
             netConnection=new NetConnection();
             netConnection.connect(connectionUrl);
             netConnection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,connectHandler);
         }                                   
         
         private function connectHandler(e:NetStatusEvent):void
         {
          if(e.info.code=="NetConnection.Connect.Success")
          {                                            
            InsertStream=new NetStream(netConnection);
              InsertStream.attachAudio(Microphone.getMicrophone());
              InsertStream.publish("stream1","live");
              getStream=new NetStream(netConnection);
              getStream.attachAudio(Microphone.getMicrophone());
              getStream.play("stream2"); // play the machine 2 stream
          }
          else
          {
              Alert.show("server Problem");
          }                                
  }
 ]]>
 </mx:Script>
```

Machine 2

```
    <mx:Script>
     <![CDATA[
         import mx.controls.Alert;
         
         private var netConnection:NetConnection;
         private var InsertStream:NetStream;
         private var getStream:NetStream;
         private var connectionUrl:String="rtmp://YOURSERVER/vchat";
         
         private function init():void
         {
             netConnection=new NetConnection();
             netConnection.connect(connectionUrl);
             netConnection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,connectHandler);
         }                                   
         
         private function connectHandler(e:NetStatusEvent):void
         {
          if(e.info.code=="NetConnection.Connect.Success")
          {                                            
              InsertStream=new NetStream(netConnection);
              InsertStream.attachAudio(Microphone.getMicrophone());
              InsertStream.publish("stream2","live");
              getStream=new NetStream(netConnection);
              getStream.attachAudio(Microphone.getMicrophone());
              getStream.play("stream1"); // play stream from the other machine
          }
          else
          {
              Alert.show("server Problem");
          }                                
  }
 ]]>
 </mx:Script>
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reply ,i have solved the problem yesterday itself,anyways thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Did you achieve on your own using similar code as suggested by Future2020's answer? If you can reply, it will be a great help. Thanks.